# How to find the mp4 video link from an Instagram link

Tags: api, video, instagram

I work on a facebook-like social network and would need to extract the mp4 from an Instagram link.

**For photos it was easy:** 
url_shared = "http://instagram.com/p/a69ygTTHKq/"
photo_to_embed = url_shared+"?size=t"

**Do you know anything similar to find out a direct link to the mp4?** I tried using their API and changing the extension from ".jpg" to ".mp4" but failed as it doesn't work all the time.

For example:
http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/bCgbJ2pgCi/ returns
`{
provider_url: "http://instagram.com/",
media_id: "487094313204187298_9762431",
title: "So did you download our "Hockey Community" app yet? If you like hockey even just a bit you should do it now!!'",
url: "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/d79af376deb011e2922a22000a1fdc29_7.jpg",
author_name: "hockeycommunity",
height: 612,
width: 612,
version: "1.0",
author_url: "http://instagram.com/hockeycommunity",
author_id: 9762431,
type: "photo",
provider_name: "Instagram"
}`

data.url = "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/d79af376deb011e2922a22000a1fdc29_**7.jpg**" and the video link is actually "http://distilleryimage2.ak.instagram.com/d79af376deb011e2922a22000a1fdc29_**101.mp4**"

Only the end of the filename changes but can't figure out what's the rule...

Source:

- http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/53880734833/moving-pictures-capturing-moments-with-video
- http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705202/11574750