# How to get video from Instagram public access API?

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I know that this API is working to get images but how about videos?
`https://www.instagram.com/username/?__a=1`

I was able to get the thumbnail of the video but not the source or the url itself.

Comment: How do you do pagination for the above url? It is just showing 12 posts for me. how do i get all posts of a profile?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you make above API call it would return `code` in it. looks something like this: `BWhyIhRDBCw`

Whenever your media nodes has `"is_video": true` you can make following call:

```
https://www.instagram.com/p/{code}/?__a=1
```

for e.g.,
https://www.instagram.com/p/BWhyIhRDBCw/?__a=1

This would return another json. which will have `video_url` you are looking for.

sample:

```
"video_url": "https://scontent-bom1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/437699b67172f450331fa732f0777b18/5A7FE0A0/t50.2886-16/20138822_486349355081174_1539674401849475072_n.mp4",
```

Comment: this url is expiring in 24 hr. Is there any url which is not expired in 24 hr ?

Answer (score 7):

Add `?__a=1&__d=dis` at behind of url like this.

https://www.instagram.com/p/BWhyIhRDBCw/?__a=1&__d=dis

It will give the json response.

FYI: This is for the public reel/video only

Comment: This URL is working but requires login most of the times to get the output.

Comment: even with the login your session will be killed really quick........

Answer (score 1):

This url working in local machine but not on my remote server.

When i try to hit from remote server its returning html content.

Comment: I guess you weren't logged in to Instagram on the server.

Answer (score 0):

To hit this api simply use volly library it will return json then u can parse json as per your need.

Comment: Please share some code example so that it will be helpful to others